# How can I trigger S3 event notifications for a single object and/or specific object keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform, hashicorp

Terraform documentation gives options to add filtering prefixes or suffixes. In a full object key, prefixes come after the bucket name itself.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.func.arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = "AWSLogs/"
    filter_suffix       = ".log"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.allow_bucket]
}
```

Instead of just a prefix, is it possible to use the full s3 object key in the event notification configuration to ensure that changes to only a specific file is considered?

For example instead of filter_prefix `"AWSLogs/"`, I want to use `mybucketname/AWSLogs/file.txt` all together.

Comment: You could set the prefix and suffix to `AWSLogs/file.txt`, that would still trigger for `AWSLogs/file.txt/AWSLogs/file.txt`, though that seems unlikely to occur in practice.

Comment: Bit of an AWS failure here to have only specified 'prefix' and 'suffix'. Also needs 'exact'. And regex, for good measure ;-) Perhaps you could send the S3 events via EventBridge and get the fine-grained filtering you need there (related [article](https://aws.plainenglish.io/why-i-wouldnt-choose-s3-bucket-notifications-again-84937286bfb6)).

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, as you've discovered, there's no built-in way to trigger an S3 event notification on only one object.

If you control the process that inserts the `AWSLogs/file.txt` object, try to insert it into a directory which will only contain that file & set the prefix.

If you don't control the process, setting the prefix and suffix to `AWSLogs/file.txt` would be the only hacky workaround.

Using Amazon EventBridge would also not work as there's [no exact matching as a type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html) so it'd be just added complexity.

AWS should add this feature in, it's long overdue.